# Global dimension of noetherian rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

In the book "An introduction to noncommutative Noetherian rings" by Goodearl and Warfield from 2004 one can find the following two open problem:

> 1. Is the Krull dimension less than or equal to the global dimension of a noetherian ring?
> 2. Is the global dimension of a noetherian ring equal to the supremum of the projective dimensions of the simple modules?

What is the status of those problems in 2017?

Comment: Rather than posting here, it would have been simpler to ask Ken Goodearl.

Comment: Re 1: any counterexample cannot have an Auslander dualising complex.